Empty bibliography table
I tried to print my bibliography as a table using biblatex-ext-tabular package. I wrote this code:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{lit.bib}


\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\begin{tabular}{|c|p{15cm}|}
  \hline}
  {\end{tabular}}
  {\printfield{labelnumber} & \printfield{title} \\
   \printfield{author} & \printfield{year} \\
   \hline}




\begin{document}
    \nocite{*} % This will print all entries in the bibliography file

\begin{refcontext}[sorting=none]
  \printbibtabular
\end{refcontext}
\end{document}

As result I have an empty table with the number of rows in which corresponds to the number of citations. But if I use default \printbibliography everything will be fine.
How to fix this?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you get error messages? Which one?

Thank you. No, I got no error messages...

Commands in the last argument of \defbibtabular that use entry data need to be wrapped in one of \plain, \plainlang, \anchor, \anchorlang or be \driver. This is explained in the documentation of \defbibtabular (§6 Tabular Bibliographies of the biblatex-ext documentation).

Within the ⟨row code⟩ argument the following macros are defined and can be used to typeset
the result of bibliography macros. Each cell should normally be wrapped into exactly one
of the following macros since they are responsible for providing the necessary entry data
to the bibliography macros.

Normally, the 'head' of your entry will be wrapped in \anchorlang and the rest in \plainlang.
Note also that author is a name list and cannot be printed with \printfield: You need to use \printnames instead. year is a field and can technically be printed with \printfield{year}, but should really be printed with \printdate because some advanced date features are only available through this interface. In the example below I used slightly higer-level bibmacros instead of bare \print... commands.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\begin{tabular}{|c|p{15cm}|}
   \hline}
  {\end{tabular}}
  {\anchorlang{%
     \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}}} &
   \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}} \\
   \plainlang{\usebibmacro{author/editor+others}} &
   \plainlang{\printdate} \\
   \hline}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\begin{refcontext}[sorting=none]
  \printbibtabular
\end{refcontext}
\end{document}



If you want the full entry in the second column, use \driver there.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\begin{tabular}{|c|p{15cm}|}
   \hline}
  {\end{tabular}}
  {\anchorlang{%
     \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}}} &
   \driver{\usebibmacro{title}}\\
   \hline}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\begin{refcontext}[sorting=none]
  \printbibtabular
\end{refcontext}
\end{document}


Thank you a lot. Do you know how to write a full citation in the second column?

@nyekitka See update. If you want something more involved, please ask a new question. (But check the biblatex-ext documentation first, maybe it already helps you.)
